# Is it possible to move code outside a functional component?

Tags: reactjs

I have a functional component who's onClick function needs to do several different things, including changing some state variables

```
    <button onClick={() => { setTimeLeft(DELAY); setDisplay(false); UpdateQuery(); window.localStorage.setItem('wasDeclined', false) }} size = 'lg'className='btn-primary'>Download Updated Data</button>
```

which is obviously atrocious from a readability perspective. If I was using a class component I could just create a method for that class that contains all the code, but I don't have this option in a functional component. I am wondering if there is another solution to make my code readable using functional components or if I should just convert this component into a class component

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rather than defining a *method*, define a *plain function* before returning the JSX:

```
const clickHandler = () => {
  setTimeLeft(DELAY);
  setDisplay(false);
  UpdateQuery();
  window.localStorage.setItem('wasDeclined', false)
};
// ...
return (
  <button
    onClick={clickHandler}
    size='lg'
    className='btn-primary'
  >Download Updated Data</button>
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Idiomatic react for this is to just use a function, just like CertainPerformance said:

```js
const MyFunctionalComponent = () => {

   const handleClick = () => {
      // do something
   }

   return <button onClick={handleClick}>Click Me</button>


}
```

It's [right in the docs as an example](https://reactjs.org/docs/handling-events.html)